# combinatorial game terminology

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I am new to combinatorial game theory, and I have a question about terminology.  As far as I can tell, in order for a game to be a combinatorial game, the game must eventually end.  That is, having a finite number of moves is part of the definition of a combinatorial game.  Is there a term to describe combinatorial games that don't necessarily end?  I want to study such games (like the Angels and Devils game), but I'm having trouble searching since I don't know what to call them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combinatorial game that doesn't necessarily end is called "loopy". However, the game in Conway's Angel problem wouldn't usually be called a loopy combinatorial game. The issue is that its win condition is different than the standard win conditions (either you win when your opponent can't make a move, or when you can't).

In standard combinatorial game theory, if play goes on forever, the game is said to be "drawn" (neither player wins). That said, if one player can force at least a draw, that's still notable.

But in the Angel problem, infinite play is a win for the angel, the angel being unable to move is a win for the devil, and the devil being unable to move is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So what kind of game is Conway's Angel Problem?  Is there a name for two player games of perfect information where one player wins if the game ends in a finite number of moves, and otherwise the other player wins?

Comment: @Dan, Aside from variants of the Angel problem (of which there are a fair number with some active research) I don't really know of too many. That said, this sort of comes up in combinatorial game theory in that you could just ask "can the angel force at least a draw?" ("can Left/Right force a draw?" in general). The issue is that on any given turn, the devil has infinitely many moves available, so that the Angel problem is a *transfinite* loopy game, a type of game there aren't really any results about yet - "transfinite" or "loopy" *alone* are hard enough to deal with.

Comment: @Dan I can't believe I forgot about Cops and Robbers on graphs and its variants, because they're separated from Combinatorial Game Theory. There's a great book on them (see http://www.math.ryerson.ca/~abonato/copsandrobbers.html ) and the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit-evasion seems related. Even if you can't find the book in a library, if you Google for cops and robbers on graphs and related terms, you'll find some descriptions/theorems.