# Non-terminating combinatorial games

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

The games I've come across thus far all have the property that their principal ideals are finite i.e the game terminates after finitely many moves so that the last position has the form {A|B} with (at least one of) A or B being empty.

How would one define "winning" in a game whose game tree has either an infinite principal ideal or, more generally, an infinite chain?

Comment: Same way as for finite games.  The only adjustment needed is that a game that never terminates is a tie.

Comment: @saulspatz how would this then affect the theory?  For example the result in Conway that states that each game G is exactly one of: positive, negative, zero or fuzzy.

Comment: I don't really know.  If I remember correctly, in "On Numbers and Games," Conway gives at least one example of a game that can last forever, but one of the players can force a win, so the infinite branch doesn't enter into the analysis in any essential way.  The game is called "traffic Jams" or something similar, I believe.

Comment: @saulspatz I see. Thanks I'll definitely have a look. The specific game I had in mind is the so-called infinite Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé/Back-and-forth game (see [Basic Model Theory](http://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/Online/doets-basic-model-theory.pdf) pp. 44 ff.) used in the model theory of the infinitary logic $L_{\infty\omega}$ (first-order logic enriched with conjunctions/disjunctions over arbitrarily many formulas) in which one of the two players is known to have a winning strategy.

Comment: Your question is closely related to [Is there a term to describe combinatorial games that don't necessarily end?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/554782/26369), but it's a little different since you're not asking about terminology, but about win conditions.

Comment: @saulspatz The "Traffic Jams" game in "On Numbers and Games" does allow infinite play, but it is [impartial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game), so has nothing corresponding to the "positive" and "negative" cases Jean-Pierre de Villiers mentioned.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks, it was only a vague recollection.  I looked at the book $40$ years ago, and I'm astonished that I remembered the name of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common approaches in the sphere of Combinatorial Game Theory.

One approach is to declare that if a game goes on forever, it is a draw. Instead of four outcomes like "positive, negative, zero, or fuzzy", there are now nine: If Left goes first, they can either guarantee a win in finite time, or Right can, or both can at best guarantee a draw. Similarly if Right moves first, for a total of $3*3=9$ outcomes. An online resource discussing the main points in this theory of "loopy" games is [Coping with cycles](http://www.msri.org/people/staff/levy/files/Book56/12siegel.pdf) by Aaron N. Siegel. Most (all?) of that material and more can be found in Chapter VI of Siegel's [Combinatorial Game Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-146).

Another approach is to grant infinite play as a win to one player. This is done in John H. Conway's [Angel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_problem), and it appears this (or something very similar) is also the convention in the "infinite Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé/Back-and-forth game" you mentioned in a comment.